# Correctly Configuring Eclipse for Lotus Notes 8.5 Plugin Development

Tags: eclipse, plugins, lotus-notes

I've reached an impasse trying to get Eclipse configured for Lotus Notes 8.5 Plug-in Development, and am frantically searching for advice on how to do it correctly.

I've searched the Web and found several articles on how to do it, but none of them seem to be working *on my machine*. (I have not attempted to do it on another machine.)

The machine's configuration is as follows:

- Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit
- Intel Core i5 CPU
- 6 GB RAM

To the best of my knowledge, the following are the prerequisites:

- JDK 6 SE (SR 2) (32-bit)
- Lotus Notes 8.5.1 Designer (32-bit)
- Lotus Expeditor Toolkit 6.2.2 (32-bit) **<-- WRONG!!!** 6.2.1!!
- Eclipse Ganymede (32-bit)

Here are the installation & configuration steps I've taken.

1. Install the JDK and JRE to c:\java
2. Modify the computer's PATH environment variable to include C:\java\jdk6\jre\bin.
3. Extract Eclipse Ganymede to c:\eclipse.
4. Install Notes to c:\lotus\notes
5. Install Expeditor to c:\lotus\expeditor
6. Configure Expeditor as described [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/expeditor-toolkit/).
7. Configure Eclipse for Notes 8.5 development as described [here](http://lekkimworld.com/pages/eclipse35_notes852.html).

The problem arises when I attempt to create a Client Services project (a plug-in). When I create the plug-in project, and Eclipse starts generating the code, the following are found in the Event Log:

- "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.ibm.pvc.tools.composite-feature.feature.group 6.1.2.200801281900 to requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.equinox.common/[3.2.0,3.3.0)."
- InvalidRegistryObjectException thrown in org.eclipse.core.resources. (Occurs multiple times.)
- ConcurrentModificationException was thrown in org.eclipse.core resources.
- And my favorite: Cannot nest 'C:Lotus/Notes/framework/rcp/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.esupport.client.product.SSC4TNF_4.0.0.20090925-1604/core' inside library 'C:Lotus/Notes/framework/rcp/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.esupport.client.product.SSC4TNF_4.0.0.20090925-1604' (This occurs for multiple packages.)

The list of exceptions goes on. I'll provide all I can if they're requested.

Clearly, I'm doing something wrong. It *cannot* be this difficult (or counter-intuitive) to get these technologies to play together.

Can someone please provide me with information about the *correct* requirements (prerequisites, et. al.) and how to set them up? This is kind of a mission critical thing, and the developer who originally did this work left no spec for his environment configuration. I'm completely in the dark.

HALP!!!!

**EDIT**

As pointed out, I'm using Expeditor 6.2.1, not 6.2.2. I verified this by viewing the license in the Expeditor folders, and viewing the contents of the site.xml file:

```
<site>
  <feature id="com.ibm.pvc.tools.composite-feature" patch="false" url="features/com.ibm.pvc.tools.composite-feature_6.2.1.20090918-0145.jar" version="6.2.1.20090918-0145">
    <category name="desktop" />
  </feature>
  <feature id="com.ibm.rcp.win32.devicetools.feature" patch="false" url="features/com.ibm.rcp.win32.devicetools.feature_6.2.1.20090918-0145.jar" version="6.2.1.20090918-0145">
    <category name="desktop" />
  </feature>
  <category-def label="desktop" name="desktop">
    <description>Lotus Expeditor Toolkit</description>
  </category-def>
</site>
```

Comment: Very strange...your site.xml says feature `com.ibm.pvc.tools.composite-feature` is version `6.2.1.20090918-0145`, but the error message claims it is version `6.1.2.200801281900` (6.2.1 vs. 6.1.2).  Could it be a mistake in Lotus Expeditor, maybe they forgot to update part of the package?

Comment: Also I found the [Getting Started guide for Expeditor 6.2](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lewiki.nsf/dx/12092008015132PMJMIRA7.htm) (the one you linked was for 6.1)

Comment: @Kevin: Yeah, this is all driving me crazy. I've torn this system down and rebuilt it from scratch so many times it's disgusting. I've tried every walk-through I can find, using every recommended combination of Eclipse, Expeditor, and Notes I can find. NONE of them seem to play well together. I am at my wits' end.

Comment: that sounds painful :(  I don't know much of anything about Lotus Expeditor, so I don't really have any other idea what might be going on.  Maybe someone with some experience working with that software could shed some light on the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you're using Lotus Expeditor Toolkit 6.2.2, yet in the first error message I read "**6.1.2**.200801281900".  This seems odd to me.  I read the first error message as:  "The 6.1.2 group feature requires Equinox Common 3.2.0 or 3.3.0".  Equinox Common for Ganymede is 3.4.*x*

Also, you may find some of the comments in [this link](http://lekkimworld.com/2008/06/05/notes_8_5_appdev_woes.html) useful...

***Edit***

I just noticed the error message says `[3.2.0,3.3.0)`.  I had assumed the closing parentheses was supposed to be a bracket, but I suppose it might be using range notation, in which case I'd guess it actually means it specifically requires 3.2.*x*.

Comment: +1, configuring the development environment in pure Eclipse definitely is difficult. It's hard to know the entire mechanism of expeditor, which adds some jars(located in a folder with version) to boot class loader and a lot of vm arguments. Using the toolkit of expeditor is a good approach.